# Chapter missplacement issue using a TTF calligraphic font

Tags: fonts, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to typeset an elegant flyer based on the report documentclass. The chapter names in the document are typeset using the Scriptina font (TTF) ([Link to font](https://www.dafont.com/scriptina.font)), and the other parts are in Comfortaa font ([Link to font](https://www.dafont.com/scriptina.font)).

The problem is that the letters l, b and d are very tall and the letters like the g go down very low for the Scriptina font (I don't know the technical name for this). This causes the chapter names to be placed differently, depending on whether there are l, b or d letters in them. The following pictures show the effect.

[image: Chapter name with tall letters]

[image: Chapter name with low letters]

As the pictures depict, the chapter names have a considerably big offset in the vertical axis when they contain the mentioned letters.

My question is: how can I place the chapter names according to the height of the number of them, rather than to the highest letter? In other words, is it possible to place all the chapter names on the same spot, in terms of the vertical axis? The space above the chapter names should be enough to contain the long letters without colliding with the top border.

The MWE is provided below.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,10pt,openany]{report}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm, top=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish,german]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}


%Par
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%Chapter format
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {}
  {\pageframe  }
  {0ex}
  {\vspace*{-10ex}\setmainfont{Scriptina}
  \fontsize{35}{\baselineskip}\selectfont \thechapter{} }
  []

%Page numbering font
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\setmainfont{Comfortaa}\fontsize{8}{\baselineskip}\selectfont\bfseries\arabic{page}}

%Counters for numbering
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}

%Table of contents on the titlepage
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\toccontents}{\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother

%author, date and title.
\title{}
\author{}
\date{\vspace{-5ex}}

%Offsets of the frame, number of the ornaments and color
\def\xoffset{0.6cm}
\def\yoffset{0.6cm}
\def\ornament{61}
\def\ornamentcolor{black}

%Command for inserting the frames
\newcommand{\pageframe}{

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, inner sep=0pt]
      %Necessary coordinates
      \coordinate (UR) at ($(current page.north east) + (-\xoffset,-\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (UL) at ($(current page.north west) + (\xoffset,-\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (LR) at ($(current page.south east) + (-\xoffset,\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (LL) at ($(current page.south west) + (\xoffset,\yoffset)$);
      \coordinate (CL) at ($(current page.west) + (\xoffset,0)$);
      \coordinate (CR) at ($(current page.east) + (-\xoffset,0)$);

      %Ornaments located at the corners of the page
      \node[anchor=north west] (ULCorner) at (UL){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor ]{\ornament}};%
      \node[anchor=north east] (URCorner) at (UR){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor, symmetry=v ]{\ornament}};%
      \node[anchor=south east] (LRCorner) at (LR){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor, symmetry=c ]{\ornament}};%
      \node[anchor=south west] (LLCorner) at (LL){%
        \pgfornament[width = 2cm,color = \ornamentcolor, symmetry=h ]{\ornament}};%

      %Ornaments between the corners: Calculates the distance between the 2 upper corners and uses it for the width of the bar ornament.
      \path (CL) let \p1 = ($(URCorner.north west) - (ULCorner.north east)$)
       in node[anchor=center, rotate=90, inner sep=-3pt] (CLBar) at (CL){\pgfornament[width=\x1 ,color = \ornamentcolor]{88}};%
      \path (CR) let \p1 = ($(URCorner.north west) - (ULCorner.north east)$)
       in node[anchor=center, rotate=90, inner sep=0pt] (CRBar) at (CR){\pgfornament[width=\x1 ,color = \ornamentcolor]{88}};%
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round]($(CLBar.east) + (0.8pt,0)$) to ($(ULCorner.south west) + (0.8pt,1pt)$){};
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round]($(CRBar.east) + (0.8pt,-1pt)$) to ($(URCorner.south east) + (0.8pt,1pt)$){};
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round]($(CLBar.west) + (0.8pt,0)$) to ($(LLCorner.north west) + (0.8pt,-1pt)$){};
      \draw[line width=1.5pt,line cap=round]($(CRBar.west) + (0.8pt,1)$) to ($(LRCorner.north east) + (0.8pt,-1pt)$){};



      %Ornaments between he corners: Top and bottom.
       \path (ULCorner.north east) to [ornament=88] (URCorner.north west) {};
       \path (LRCorner.south west) to [ornament=88] (LLCorner.south east) {};

  \end{tikzpicture}}




\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
 \pageframe

\setmainfont{Scriptina}

 \begin{center}
 {\fontsize{60}{\baselineskip}\selectfont Lorem \\[\baselineskip] 
 a\\[\baselineskip]
 Ipsum}
 \end{center} 
\vspace{4\baselineskip}

 \fontsize{35}{\baselineskip}\selectfont
 Dolor

 \fontsize{12}{\baselineskip}\selectfont 
 \setmainfont{Comfortaa}
\toccontents
\clearpage\cleardoublepage

\end{titlepage}


\maketitle

\chapter{A b c d t l}
\chapter{E m r g}
\chapter{aconme}
\chapter{}



\end{document}
```

Comment: You can put the titles in a box of zero height, like `\chapter{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{A b c d t l}}`. The letters won't affect the total title height then.

Comment: Don't use \setmainfont in this places. Define  font families with `\newfontfamily` and use them.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan Please make your comment an answer to give the OP the ability to accept... (You can include one or more alternatives like tikz usage[mot tested])

Comment: the actual issue is your line `\fontsize{35}{\baselineskip}\selectfont ` that is setting 35pt high letters on a default 12pt baseline so you get uneven spacing as you describe. `\fontsize{35}{40pt}\selectfont ` would be more reasonable

Comment: Using `\def` that way is really not wise: have you checked you aren't overwriting anything? `\newcommand` is a much better option.

Comment: You shouldn't need `\clearpage\cleardoublepage` in the `titlepage` environment and it doesn't make sense here. `\clearpage\cleardoublepage` doesn't make sense anyway.